# Post status update: "Error publishing message"

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I'm using the latest SDK(4.1.1) and the sample application *HelloFacebookSamp* for testing a case where if the post status failed when using the native Facebook app on the phone.

**Case**:
User post and we wait for the *onSuccess* from the *FacebookCallback* to complete.

**Problem**:
If the post failed and we get a *onError* (Error publishing message) from the *FacebookCallback*. The user gets a notification in the *notification drawer*, from the native app to retry. If the user retry, we don't get a *onSuccess* event and can't complete.

So the user has completed the status update but there is no way to for us to know it.

**Reproduce:**
 - Install sample and facebook app
 - Press *Post Status Update*
 - Turn off Wifi/Data before sharing.
 - Sharing failes and user gets a notification to retry.
 - Turn on Wifi/Data and retry

Is there any good way to handle this and get a *onSuccess* event?

Comment: Why do you need to know that the user completed the action?

Comment: We are using it as a way to reward dedicated users with virtual rewards. So if the user post an status update about us, he/she gets 'achievement'.

Comment: You should not incentivize posting status updates per https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse  "Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place."